# Amplify Auth SignUp auto send another request and throw Error: No credentials, applicationId or region

Tags: aws-amplify

I have 2 projects which are using the same code like this:

```
Auth.signUp({ username, password, attributes })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
  .finally(() => console.log('done'));
```

Just like this: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#sign-up

Here is the problem show out:

- In my old project, everything is ok, just 1 request is sign up send to AWS and got some data from it: https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/
- In my new project, I have another request go to AWS after the sign up request. There are:
  https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/
  And : https://cognito-identity.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ which is after the first one and its response is :
  message: "Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool."
  __type: "NotAuthorizedException"

After that, I got the error in console: Error: No credentials, applicationId or region.

Not sure why is the old project is working fine but with this one, this error show up. Is it because the different in amplify ?

Thanks.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by using

```
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
```

istead of

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
```

Comment: Solved it for me too. Can someone please explain why this resolves the issue?

Comment: I am using was-amplify and was-amplify-react-native package. Does it work if I change the package imports as mentioned above?

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem is with the Analytics package of AWS from my understanding of this [link](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3484). Disabling it like so worked for me

```
import config from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure({
    ...config,
    Analytics: { 
      disabled: true
    }
});
```

Comment: this was my problem as well in Jan 2022